# I am new to ROS. Could someone tell me how to install the frontier exploration package?

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that I should clone the repository from git. I have don't that. Then what should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217568/i-am-new-to-ros.-could-someone-tell-me-how-to-install-the-frontier-exploration-package-?/) by [beyescay](https://answers.ros.org/users/23855/beyescay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need the executable of the package `frontier_exploration`. You have two options, actually: 1) You can download the executable of the package for Ubuntu OS using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-frontier-exploration
```

assuming that you have Indigo and Ubuntu. 2) You can clone the repository and get the source codes. To generate the executable, you need to compile the source codes, as usual. You should place that package in your workspace and run `catkin_make` to build the packages in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2015-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2015-09-14**:
I've never had anyone explain option 2 before so well.  Thanks.  I thought compiling and including someone's else's source package on my machine would be more difficult than that.  But it makes perfect sense.